# Change domain for load balancer's SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I am going around in circles for the past hour trying to change the domain for HTTP(S) Load Balancer's SSL certificates.

I can't seem to find an option from the console or CLI to change/update the domains. After created a new one, I cannot delete the old one because it is attached to the load balancer. To remove the old SSL certificate, I have to delete the LB and its dependencies, and to go through all the steps to create the load balancer again.

May I know if it is a bug or expected behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) You cannot change an SSL certificate once issued. Instead, create a new SSL certificate. 2) SSL certificates are attached to frontends. You can issue a new certificate and optionally delete the old one.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley If I create a new SSL, I can't seem to be able to delete the old SSL. It is tied to the load balancer. To remove the old SSL, I need to delete the entire loadbalancer and to create a new one. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can delete an SSL certificate, you must first update each target proxy that references the certificate. For each target proxy, run the appropriate gcloud update command to update the target proxy's CERTIFICATE_LIST such that it no longer includes the SSL certificate you need to delete.

Please find below steps to replacing SSL certificates.

1.Create a new SSL certificate resource. The new SSL certificate must have a unique name within the project.
2. Update the target proxy so that its list of SSL certificate(s) includes the new SSL certificate in the first position to make it the primary certificate. After the new certificate, include any existing SSL certificates that you want to retain. Make sure to exclude the old SSL certificate that you no longer need. To avoid downtime, run a single gcloud command with the --ssl-certificates flag. For example:

For external HTTP(S) load balancers:

Use the gcloud compute target-https-proxies update command with the --global flag.

gcloud compute target-https-proxies update TARGET_PROXY_NAME 
--global 
--ssl-certificates=new-ssl-cert,other-certificates 
--global-ssl-certificates.

For internal HTTP(S) load balancers:

gcloud compute target-https-proxies update TARGET_PROXY_NAME 
--region REGION 
--ssl-certificates=new-ssl-cert,other-certificates 
--global-ssl-certificates

For SSL proxy load balancers:

Use the gcloud compute target-ssl-proxies update command with the --backend-service flag.

gcloud compute target-ssl-proxies update TARGET_PROXY_NAME 
--ssl-certificates=new-ssl-cert,other-certificates

3. Verify that the load balancer is serving the replacement certificate by running the following OpenSSL command:

echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect IP_ADDRESS:443 -verify 99 -verify_return_error

4. Wait 15 minutes to ensure that the replacement certificate is available to all Google Front Ends (GFEs).
5. (Optional) Delete the old SSL certificate.

For further reading please follow the links below:
Deleting/ Replacing SSL certificates :

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#delete-ssl-cert-resource

Replacing an existing SSL certificate

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#replace-ssl